# Required request body is missing when sending OAuth 2.0 POST request

Tags: spring

I am trying to send the following post request to my /sign-up endpoint.

```
{
    "message": "Hello! My name is Alexandru and I would like to help with translations on your website. I am highly motivated person.",
    "preferredLanguageCodes": ["RO", "FR"]
}

@PostMapping(path = "/sign-up")
public void signup(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signupRequest, @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) throws IOException {
    applicationService.signup(principal, signupRequest);
}

@Data
public class SignupRequest {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 50)
    private String message;
    @NotEmpty
    private List<String> preferredLanguageCodes;
}
```

However, the first time I call my endpoint from Postman, it always says that the request body is missing. The second time I call it, it works with no issues and returns a 200.

Comment: Did you tried without oauth? Is the request being sent?

Comment: Yes, I have just tried, and I am getting the exact same error.

Comment: Could you check inside Postman if the Content-Length header is checked to be sent?